# MVC3 submit returning null on my complex data type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC3 project I have the following model:

```
public class CustomerModules
{
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public int CustId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ActiveDate { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerModuleList
{
    public IEnumerable<CustomerModules> Modules { get; set; }
}
```

My controller is as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditModules(int custNo)
{
    var model = new CustomerModuleList
    {
        Modules = _customerModules.LoadModulesByCustomerId(custNo)
    };

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditModules(CustomerModuleList model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       var custId = model.Modules.First().CustId;

       _customerModules.UpdateCustomerModules(model.Modules, custId);
    }

    return View(model);

}
```

And my view snippet is:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("EditModules","Admin",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){ %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>CustomerModuleList</legend>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Module Name</th>
                <th>Active</th>
                <th>Active Date</th>
            </tr>
            <% foreach (var module in Model.Modules){%>
                <tr>

                    <td><%:Html.Label(module.ModuleName) %></td>
                    <td>
                        <%CustomerModules module1 = module;%>
                        <%:Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>module1.IsActive) %>
                    </td>
                    <td><%:Html.Label(module.ActiveDate.ToString()) %></td>
                </tr>
            <% } %>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>
```

When I submit back to the controller the `IEnumerable<CustomerModules>` Modules comes back as a null.  I would like to know how you can submit an `IEnumerable` of a complex type in MVC3? Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're not specifying that the object your form is submitting is of type CustomerModuleList.

In your views/Shared/EditorTemplates file create views named CustomerModuleList.cshtml and CustomerModules.cshtml.

In CustomerModuleList.cshtml put

```
@model CustomerModuleList
<% foreach (var module in Model.Modules){%>
            Html.EditorFor(x => module);
        <% } %>
```

and then in CustomerModules.cshtml stick

```
@model CustomerModules
<tr>
                <td><%:Html.Label(Model.ModuleName) %></td>
                <td>
                    <%:Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.IsActive) %>
                </td>
                <td><%:Html.Label(Model.ActiveDate.ToString()) %></td>
            </tr>
```

then in your view snippet replace the for loop with

```
Html.EditorFor(x => Model)
```

tested this with a different IEnumerable of a type I made and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is a similar but unrelated problem.  I'm adding it here in hopes that I will save some other poor developer 4+hours of troubleshooting.  I don't know if this was just on my system but...in MVC 3 I found that if the Model contains any kind of list property (list, ienumerable, array...) with the name Member or OrgMember the model binder will completely fail!  Go figure.

Comment: Big thanks, Im using MVC 4 and had the same issue. however my lists were called something else, I created this question, but i found renaming the list names helped...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982096/strange-behaviour-with-mvc-posting-list

Answer (score 1):

Please check this post : http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/ and I hope it helps you fix the issues in your app :)

PS: The example works on MVC3 too without any additional effort.